# How to Translate api error

Tags: magento2, localisation

I want to translate api error messages in arabic. please let me know how I can do it. I have tried using csv but not working.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

after adding translation in csv file you need to run static content deploy command.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to close this question. Thanks. :)